# remove nul characters from text file using vbs

Tags: vbscript, null

I have text files that are approximately 6MB in size. There are some lines that contain the NULL (Chr(0))character that I would like to remove.
I have two methods to do this: using Asc()=0 but this takes approximately 50s to complete, the other method uses InStr (line, Chr(0)) =0 (fast ~ 4sec)but the results remove vital info from the lines which contain the NULL characters.

First line of text file as example:

```
@@MMCIBN.000NULL7NULL076059NULL7653NULL1375686349NULL2528NULL780608NULL10700NULL\NULL_NC_ACT.DIR\CFG_RESET.INI
```

First method (works but VERY slow)

```
function normalise (textFile )

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
writeTo = fso.BuildPath(tempFolder, saveTo & ("\Output.arc"))
Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(writeTo)
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(textFile,1)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream 
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)
    If Asc(strCharacters) = 0 Then
        objOutFile.Write ""
        nul = true
    Else
        if nul = true then
            objOutFile.Write(VbLf & strCharacters)
        else
            objOutFile.Write(strCharacters)
        end if
    nul = false
    End If
Loop

objOutFile.close
end function
```

The output looks like this:

```
@@MMCIBN.000
7
076059
7653
1375686349
2528
780608
10700
\
_NC_ACT.DIR\CFG_RESET.INI
```

Second method code:

```
filename = WScript.Arguments(0)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sDate = Year(Now()) & Right("0" & Month(now()), 2) & Right("00" & Day(Now()), 2)
file = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetFile(filename).ParentFolder.Path, saveTo & "Output " & sDate & ".arc")
Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(file)
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    line = f.ReadLine

    If (InStr(line, Chr(0)) > 0) Then 
        line = Left(line, InStr(line, Chr(0)) - 1) & Right(line, InStr(line, Chr(0)) + 1)
    end if

    objOutFile.WriteLine line

Loop

f.Close
```

but then the output is:

```
@@MMCIBN.000\CFG_RESET.INI
```

Can someone please guide me how to remove the NULLS quickly without losing information. I have thought to try and use the second method to scan for which line numbers need updating and then feed this to the first method to try and speed things up, but quite honestly I have no idea where to even start doing this!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried [`Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954(v=vs.84).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have, the script gives no output but has high CPU and memory usage, thats all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the first method is just replacing each `NULL` with a newline. If that's all you need, you can just do this:

**Updated:**

OK, sounds like you need to replace each *set* of NULLs with a newline. Let's try this instead:

```
strText = fso.OpenTextFile(textFile, 1).ReadAll()

With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\x00+"
    .Global = True
    strText = .Replace(strText, vbCrLf)
End With

objOutFile.Write strText
```

**Update 2:**

I think the `Read/ReadAll` methods of the `TextStream` class are having trouble dealing with the mix of text and binary data. Let's use an `ADO Stream` object to read the data instead.

```
' Read the "text" file using a Stream object...
Const adTypeText = 2

With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = adTypeText
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile textFile
    .Charset = "us-ascii"
    strText = .ReadText()
End With

' Now do our regex replacement...
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\x00+"
    .Global = True
    strText = .Replace(strText, vbCrLf)
End With

' Now write using a standard TextStream...
With fso.CreateTextFile(file)
    .Write strText
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: The first method checks character by character, if I understand the method correctly (I dabble with software, not a pro :-)) The NULLs are replaced by "", if the previous character was *real* then it gives the VBCrLf for a new line, otherwise will continue on the same line (I left out the long strings of NULLs for space and clarity) I tried this replace method but there is no output from the script at all with high CPU usage and high memory usage, thats it. Thanks for your help thus far...

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to look for _sets_ of NULL instead instead of replacing each instance with a newline. See if that helps.

Comment: Fist line is incomplete, next line shows actually line 111412 ! my code that i have tried is as follows:                                                                              `textFile = WScript.Arguments(0)`

`Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

`writeTo = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetFile(textFile).ParentFolder.Path, saveTo & "Output.arc")`
`Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile(writeTo)`
`strText = fso.OpenTextFile(textFile, 1).ReadAll()`

`With New RegExp`
`    .Pattern = "\x00+"`
    .Global = True
    strText = .Replace(strText, vbCrLf)
End With

objOutFile.Write strText`

Comment: Is there no way to improve method 2, the If ~ End if section? I dont know and understand enough to really improve on this myself. I have tried Trim but this is not working

Comment: See **Update 2**. I think we'll need to avoid using `Read/ReadAll` because of the nature of your "text" file. **Update 2** shows how to read the file using an `ADO Stream` object instead. It took about 5 seconds to read a 6 MB file using this method on my PC. The regex replacement and rewrite were < 1 second total.

Comment: BTW, to answer your question, your second method is only finding and removing the _first_ instance of NULL on each line. You'd need to use `InStr()` in a loop (or use a function like `Replace()`) to update all occurrences on that line. That's why your second method is losing information (and is only 4 seconds, ;)).

Comment: Thank you, (near) perfect! OK for me this is fine, I *should* be able to help myself further from here, lots of reading up to do concerning ADO Stream. For interest, if you want to investigate (It does not negatively affect me), for the first time ever, the first line has a square and a ~ as the first two characters before the @@MMCIBN      Thank you for your help!(ANSWERED)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this method (update2) for reading a MS-Access lock file (Null characters terminated strings in 64 byte records)  and the ADODB.Stream didn't want to open an already in use file. So I changed that part to :

```
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.GetFile(Lfile)
    z = f.Size
    set ts = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, 0) 'TristateFalse   
    strLog = ts.Read(z)
    ts.Close
    set f = nothing
    ' replace 00 with spaces
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "\x00+"
        .Global = True
        strLog = .Replace(strLog, " ")
    End With
    ' read MS-Access computername and username
    for r = 1 to len(strLog) step 64
        fnd = trim(mid(strLog,r, 32)) & ", " &  trim(mid(strLog,r+32, 32)) & vbCrLf
        strRpt = strRpt & fnd
    next
```